# Why doesn't css :not work in some cases?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why does the `:not` selector not work at all in this case:

```
a {
  color:red;
}

div a:not(.special a) {
  color: green;
}
```

In, for example:

```
<div>
  <span>hello<a href="#">link</a></span>
</div>
<div class="special">
  <span>hello<a href="#">link</a></span>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="#"> something else</a>
</p>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eguecrvz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:not()` currently doesn't allow combinators or any more than one simple selector (such as `.special` or `a`) as an argument. A future specification will expand `:not()` to accept any number of complex selectors, and once browsers support it your selector `div a:not(.special a)` will work exactly as intended.

In the meantime, it is not possible to write a selector for "an `a` element that does not have a `.special` ancestor element." You will need to [override](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/eguecrvz/3) with an additional `.special a` selector in your rule that applies to `a` elements in general:

```
a, .special a {
  color:red;
}

div a {
  color: green;
}
```

The additional specificity of `.special a` will ensure that it overrides `div a`, but if specificity is a problem you will need to rearrange your rulesets.

Comment: As in "In Selectors Level 3, only a single simple selector was allowed as the argument" - https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation ? No browsers support selectors level 4?

Comment: @NoBugs: Yeah it's still pretty new (well I'd hardly consider 5 years new, but alas). There is only one shipping implementation, and it is neither Google Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm probably missing something obvious here, but isn't the OP just looking for `div:not(.special) a {color: green;}`?

Comment: @Boaz: That will color it green in `<div><p class=special><a>` when it should be red because of the `p.special`.

Answer (score 1):

`special` is class of `div` not `anchor`.

Change css like:

```
div:not(.special) a{
  color: green;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eguecrvz/2/)**

**Edit:**

If you want all link green except `.special` the do like:

```
a {
  color:green;
}

.special a{
   color: red;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eguecrvz/5/)**

Comment: So, no way to have a space within :not, and no way to select something without .special ancestor element somewhere?

Comment: @NoBugs Sorry i can't understood that. What is your expected output?

Comment: @ketan Your answer is correct. The OP is confused with my answer that I did mistakenly.

Comment: That is not the same as saying an a that is not within a ".special". Any div could be not(.special) outside it.

Comment: @NoBugs Check my edited. I think this is what you want.

Comment: I know that in the simple case that works obviously, my question is why :not is broken.

Comment: @NoBugs `:not` is not broken. You write `:not` on  `.special`. Whcih is not class of div. You write wrong css.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't css `:not` work in some cases?
>
> ```
> div a:not(.special a) {
>    color: green
> }
> ```

Because the negation pseudo-class (`:not`) only takes a *simple selector* as an argument.

Your argument `(.special a)` represents a *descendant selector* which does not qualify.

> [**6.6.7. The negation
>   pseudo-class**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)
>
> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking
>   a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
>   argument.

What is a simple selector?

> [**4. Selector syntax**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn)
>
> A simple selector is either a *type selector*, *universal selector*,
>   *attribute selector*, *class selector*, *ID selector*, or *pseudo-class*.